# Performing update without union

Tags: sql, netezza

I have an optimization question for you. I made following SQL update statement:

```
UPDATE table1
  set c1 = 
    case
        condition1/result1
        condition2/result2
    end,
  set c2 = 
    case
        condition1/result3
        condition2/result4
    end
where condition
```

... and everything works perfectly.

The thing is I have 11 tables with exactly the same structure and need to make an update for every single one of them. I can perform my task with union function and run all of them at once.

I'd like learn something new and perform my task with a loop or declare a function. Could you please provide me with guidance how to make it and which way is more efficient.

Thank you very much

Comment: has you tested if getting rid of the case and breaking it in 2 updates improves performance?

Comment: @jean the thing is that the query is fine. I want to create a loop or declare variable on table.

Comment: I know, just pointing other direction, btw if its a one time query you can use a query to output a query and run it. If its dynamicaly picks from some tables you can use a EXEC SQL (if its mssql, nto sure about other DBMS) if it's always the same tables just write it down (and good luck with mainteance)